# Sublime Text2 autocomplete on custom keys

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

Can auto-complete be invoked on custom keys(not Ctrl+Space)?

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, read about keybindings in the documentation:
http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html

You'll need to copy these to your User keybindings and alter them:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+space"], "command": "auto_complete" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+space"], "command": "replace_completion_with_auto_complete", "context":
    [
        { "key": "last_command", "operator": "equal", "operand": "insert_best_completion" },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false },
        { "key": "setting.tab_completion", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
},
```