# Autocomplete on space in SublimeText 2

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2

I'd like the autocomplete function of SublimeText 2 to insert the currently selected option when I hit space (like IntelliSense in VisualStudio).

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423140/sublime-text2-autocomplete-on-custom-keys) question, and tried to modify the solution (it's a custom key binding). But the best I got is this, and this deletes whatever I begun to write instead of completing it:

```
{ "keys": [":"], "command": "replace_completion_with_auto_complete", "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.tab_completion", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize your question: You want to commit the autocompletion on space,  if it is visible.
The corresponding keybinding is:

```js
{
    "keys": [" "], "command": "commit_completion", "context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible" }
    ]
},
```